# Why there is no output when invoking \usebox{\mybox} outside the minipage in which \sbox{\mybox}{contents} is invoked?

Tags: macros, boxes, minipage

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{document}


\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\sbox{\mybox}{from first minipage}
\usebox{\mybox}
\end{minipage}%
}

%nothing rendered
\fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}

\vspace{3cm}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
%nothing rendered
\usebox{\mybox}
\end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no output because of TeX's scoping rules. This can be demonstrated by a simpler example and using `\def` rather than boxes.

```
\begin{minipage}{3cm} 
  \def\fortytwo{42}
  \fortytwo
\end{minipage}
```

This will typeset 42 within the minipage, but if you try and use `\fortytwo` outside the minipage you will get an error `Undefined control sequence'.

TeX's scoping rules work similarly to *local* and *global* scope in other programming languages. However in TeX it is a bit different. Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\fortytwo{42}
\begin{minipage}{2cm} 
      \fortytwo
      \def\fortytwo{43}
      \fortytwo
    \end{minipage}
\fortytwo
\end{document}
```

As you will observe once you return to the outside of a macro, the old definition is retained, so in the example above you will get a 43 within the minipage but 42 outside it!

Using boxes, we can demonstrate this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{Outside scope}

\begin{minipage}{3cm}
  \sbox{\mybox}{from first minipage}
  \usebox\mybox
\end{minipage}

\usebox{\mybox}

\end{document}
```

This will typeset `from first minipage` within the minipage and `Outside scope` outside the minipage.

Comment: A good answer, but I would also add how to fix this: prefix the `\def` or the `\sbox` with `\global`; in this case, `\global\sbox{\mybox}{from first minipage}`.  (And for `\def`, this becomes `\gdef`.)

Comment: `\usebox` expands to `\leavevmode\copy#1\relax`. Your final example is flawed because you didn't use `\sbox` so the box was always empty.

Comment: Also, I think you wanted to use `\newsavebox` (although the difference is fairly minor).

Comment: @TH Thanks for pointing the flaw and I have edited for completeness. `

Comment: @Antal thanks for the comment. This will indeed save the `\mybox` globally.

Comment: how to make a global effect when calling \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}...\end{lrbox} inside minipage? Because I cannnot use \global prefix unlike \sbox.

Comment: @xport: The easiest may be to adapt the definition of the lrbox environment to become `\newenvironment {glrbox} [1] {\global\setbox#1\hbox\bgroup \@endpefalse \color@setgroup \ignorespaces} {\unskip\color@endgroup\egroup}`. I'm not sure about colors, though.